# Install Shield Limited Edition tutorial for creating a setup file for web application in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, windows-installer, installshield-le

I have been searching since 2 hours on Google to find out a step by step tutorial for creating a setup project for Web Application in Visual Studio 2012, but I couldn't find any.

Can anyone guide me or point me to a simple tutorial for creating a setup project using `Install Shield Limited Edition 2012` for a web application to be deployed on `IIS 7.5`?

Answer (score 0):

Usually web application's are deployed with a simple XCopy. Why do you need an bloated setup?